# Can this recursive function be optimized?

Tags: arrays, c, function, recursion, optimization

Is there a way to optimize the first defined function in attached code?

I wonder if the exercise I've done can be optimized for readability and performance. The exercise was about determining if the array, which stores the integer values is incrementally well sorted (every digit is greater than the previous [i.e. 1,2,3,4,5]), just incrementally sorted (the numbers are generally incrementally sorted, but there can be few with the same values in a row [i.e. 1,3,3,5]), or not sorted at all incrementally [i.e. 4,2,1].

The exercise has to be done by using recursive approach in the most optimized way. Below is my solution proposition:

```
// find if the array is well sorted incrementally, sorted incrementally or not sorted at all
// the function should return 1 if array is well sorted or just sorted and return 0 otherwise
// the function should pass by refference 1 if the array is well sorted or 0 otherwise
// the result will be thus determined based on those two parameters in separate function
// recursive approach

#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE1 5 // constants for ready arrays tests
#define SIZE2 4 // ...
#define SIZE3 3 // ...

int findIfArrayIsSorted(int array[], int size, int *precision);
void printResult(int result, int precision);
void specifyInputArraySize(int *size);
void inputArrayElements(int array[], int size);
void printArrayElements(int array[], int size);

int findIfArrayIsSorted(int array[], int size, int *precision)
{
    if (size > 1)
    {
        if (array[size-1] < array[size-2])
        {
            *precision = 0;
            return 0;
        }
        else if (array[size-1] == array[size-2])
        {
            *precision = 0;
            return findIfArrayIsSorted(array, size - 1, precision);
        }
        else if (array[size-1] > array[size-2])
            return findIfArrayIsSorted(array, size - 1, precision);
    }
    return 1;
}

void printResult(int result, int precision)
{
    if (result == 1 && precision == 1)
        printf("This array is well sorted\n");
    else if (result == 1 && precision == 0)
        printf("This array is sorted\n");
    else
        printf("This array isn't sorted\n");
}

void specifyInputArraySize(int *size)
{
    printf("Please enter the size: ");
    scanf("%d", size);
}

void inputArrayElements(int array[], int size)
{
    int i;
    printf("Please input array elements (one by one):\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}

void printArrayElements(int array[], int size)
{
    int i;
    printf("The elements stored in an array are:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("Element[%d] is %d\n", i, array[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int result;
    int precision;

    // tests for ready arrays
    int numArrayW[SIZE1] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int numArrayS[SIZE2] = {1, 3, 3, 5};
    int numArrayU[SIZE3] = {4, 2, 1};

    precision = 1; // default assumption
    printArrayElements(numArrayW, SIZE1);
    result = findIfArrayIsSorted(numArrayW, SIZE1, &precision);
    printResult(result, precision);

    precision = 1; // default assumption
    printArrayElements(numArrayS, SIZE2);
    result = findIfArrayIsSorted(numArrayS, SIZE2, &precision);
    printResult(result, precision);

    precision = 1; // default assumption
    printArrayElements(numArrayU, SIZE3);
    result = findIfArrayIsSorted(numArrayU, SIZE3, &precision);
    printResult(result, precision);

    // test for inputted array

    int size;
    precision = 1; // default assumption
    specifyInputArraySize(&size);
    int numInputtedArray[size];
    inputArrayElements(numInputtedArray, size);
    printArrayElements(numInputtedArray, size);
    result = findIfArrayIsSorted(numInputtedArray, size, &precision);
    printResult(result, precision);

    return 0;
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone will find more optimized solution, thanks.

Comment: This might be better asked here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Note that your main function doesn't reset `precision` between calls, which is a "bug".

Comment: You don't have to check `>` when `<` and `==` already evaluated to `false`.

Comment: That's right, thanks. I've corrected that. My mistake was probably because the ready arrays tests were made to just show how the exercise and it's functionality should look like. The program at the end will be just mainly one call of 'findIfArrayIsSorted' function.

Comment: The function can be optimized for performance and probably also for readability by making it iterative instead of recursive.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know, exactly, I did the same exercise in iterative way, but the recursive way was also asked to struggle a bit to practice recursion calls.

Comment: @mch sorry, what did you mean by saying that == already evaluate to false?

Comment: Just pass the previous element as a *function argument*, and test the current element. I don't get why you check previous and next previous. You won't have to worry about underflow either.

Comment: It's odd that you recurse on only decreasing size instead of also increasing array (start).  Switching that could allow improved readability, at least, and maybe improved performance, as you would always compare `array[0]` with `array[1]` (for different values of `array`).

Comment: When you have `if (array[size-1] < array[size-2])` and then `else if (array[size-1] == array[size-2])`, then you can replace `else if (array[size-1] > array[size-2])` by `else`. There is no 4th option. The value is either smaller, equal or bigger. If it is not smaller nor equal, it must be bigger, no need to check that.

Comment: @mch that's a good point, I was considering using just else, but it seemed to me that more clear at first glance would be if I use else if with condition. Is it a matter of preference? Does it have any impact on RAM/CPU usage?

Comment: "I use recursion to practice recursion" is like saying "I plow the field by hand with a rusty shovel instead of a tractor because I need to practice shovelling". _Why_ do you need to practice that when the tractor is available? When will you ever plow the field by hand in your professional farmer career? The only farmer who ever gets such a bad idea ought to be that confused one who insisted on practicing doing it by hand when they were learning the trade.

Comment: @Lundin That's very wise what you've written. I am aware of the concept, which you've described, but I am just on the beginning of my learning journey. I know it's not necessary to use recursion here, but why I shouldn't try to use the other way just for the curiosity? It's like swapping two variables without temp variable, it's not necessary, even it's not useful, but you never know when the recruiter will ask to do the similar kind of task.

Comment: @MrSigma123 Long as you are aware of what's useful in real-world programs and what's just fooling around for fun. Recursion has almost no place in real-world programs, but it is plenty helpful for "Code Golf" recreational programming, for example. As for future interviews, maybe don't take the farming job where the recruiter asks you to "show me how to switch stalls for these two cows without using your hands", because that doesn't sound like a very serious farm to work at - to begin with, they put a muppet in charge of recruiting...

Comment: @Lundin hah, good point. Thats right, I should concentrate on creating useful programs for my coding skills development instead goofing around with i.e. recursion exercises. Thanks

Comment: If the array isn't sorted, the function doesn't care to fulfil the obligation `should pass by refference 1 if the array is well sorted or 0 otherwise`; shall this be considered correct?

Comment: @Armali that's right, I missed one line where in case of not sorted array there should be returned 0 by reference, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This variant optimizes for neither readability nor performance, but rather for usability and conformance, because it doesn't require the caller to preset the reference argument with the *default assumption* 1.

```
int findIfArrayIsSorted(int array[], int size, int *precision)
{
    if (size <= 1) return *precision = 1;

    if (array[size-1] < array[size-2]) return *precision = 0;

    int sorted = findIfArrayIsSorted(array, size-1, precision);
    *precision &= array[size-1] > array[size-2];
    return sorted;
}
```